# Object copying, Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to model car object in Kotlin, and I have a following structure:

```
data class CarModel(
    val brand: Brand, val modelName: String
) {
    val versionNumber = VersionNumber(value = 1)


    override fun toString(): String {
        return "CarModel(brand=$brand, modelName=$modelName, versionNumber=${versionNumber.value})"
    }

    fun incrementVersionNumber(): CarModel {
        val newCarModel = this.copy()
        newCarModel.versionNumber = this.versionNumber.value + 1 //ERROR (Val cannot be reassigned)

        return newCarModel
    }
}

data class VersionNumber(val value: Int) {}
```

Since version number always has to be 1 initially, the idea is to allow incrementation of the version number only through `incrementVersionNumber` method. I tried to achieve that with object cloning, meaning return the copy of the object only with version number changed. But for that to work i would need to change the `versionNumber` property to var but i want to keep it immutable. Is there some way to get this to work while keeping the `versionNumber` property as `val`

Comment: You could make `CarModel` a regular class (instead of a data class) and add a private constructor accepting version number. You then call this constructor inside `incrementVersionNumber`.

Comment: Change the `value` of `VersionNumber` to a `var`

Comment: With a data class, you would be able to circumvent the expected behaviour anyway, using `copy`.

Comment: @MatthewLayton Could you please explain what do you mean by that ?

Comment: @indee423 Sure, say I have `carInstance` with `versionNumber.value` equal to `1`, I could just do `carInstance.copy(versionNumber = VersionNumber(0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely lock down unexpected behaviour; for example, someone deliberately changing `versionNumber` to 0, then you would need to use a regular class rather than a data class, as you'll be able to return new instances with any of the properties changed using `copy()`.

Consider this approach, which uses a secondary constructor to prevent erroneous entries on instantiation.

```kotlin
class CarModel private constructor (val brand: Brand, val modelName: String, val versionNumber: VersionNumber) {
    
    constructor(brand: Brand, modelName: String) : this(brand, modelName, VersionNumber())
    
    fun incrementVersionNumber(): CarModel {
        return CarModel(brand, modelName, VersionNumber(versionNumber.value + 1))
    }
    
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "CarModel(brand=$brand, modelName=$modelName, versionNumber=${versionNumber.value})"
    }
}

data class VersionNumber(val value: Int = 1)
```

You could also introduce an init block to check that version is greater than zero, but you won't be able to check that the current version number is an increment of the previous instance:

```kotlin
data class CarModel(val brand: Brand, val modelName: String, val versionNumber: VersionNumber = VersionNumber()) {

    init {
        require(versionNumber.value > 0) { "Version number must be greater than zero." }
    }
    
    fun incrementVersionNumber(): CarModel {
        return CarModel(brand, modelName, VersionNumber(versionNumber.value + 1))
    }
    
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "CarModel(brand=$brand, modelName=$modelName, versionNumber=${versionNumber.value})"
    }
}
```

You could also move the require check to the `VersionNumber` class:

```kotlin
data class VersionNumber(val value: Int = 1) {
    init {
        require(value > 0) { "Version number must be greater than zero." }
    }
}
```

Finally, if you really want a class to behave like a data class, then you will need to override the default implementations for `equals` and `hashCode` in order to obtain proper value semantics:

```kotlin
class CarModel(val brand: Brand, val modelName: String, val versionNumber: VersionNumber = VersionNumber()) {
    
    fun incrementVersionNumber(): CarModel {
        return CarModel(brand, modelName, VersionNumber(versionNumber.value + 1))
    }
    
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return this === other
                || other is CarModel
                && other.brand == brand
                && other.modelName == modelName
                && other.versionNumber == versionNumber
    }
    
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return Objects.hash(brand, modelName, versionNumber)
    }
    
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "CarModel(brand=$brand, modelName=$modelName, versionNumber=${versionNumber.value})"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do what you ask with a private constructor (including the version number), a factory method to create new instances and the copy method to create instances with versions != 1.

```
data class CarModel private constructor(
    val brand: Brand, val modelName: String, val versionNumber: VersionNumber
) {
    companion object {
        fun create(brand: Brand, modelName: String): CarModel {
             return CarModel(brand, modelName, VersionNumber(1))
        }
    }
    fun incrementVersionNumber(): CarModel =
        this.copy(versionNumber = VersionNumber(versionNumber.value + 1))
}
```

Also you are probably easier off using an inline class for VersionNumber instead.

Comment: A factory method is not necessary. You can use a secondary (public) constructor if you prefer.

Comment: But this would allow to create a CarModel object with any ```versionNumber```

Comment: @indee423 No, only version==1 is possible as that is the only thing that the factory (or secondary constructor) allow you to do

Comment: The Kotlin compiler will complain about a data class's primary constructor being private, because it's effectively public accessible via the data classes `copy` method.

Comment: @MatthewLayton that is a fair remark yes, you would indeed need a regular class to plug that hole if that is a concern (ie you really want to make it difficult for the user to do it instead of indicating that they shouldn't)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a private setter in your `CarModel` class:

```
var versionNumber: VersionNumber = VersionNumber(value = 1)
    private set

fun incrementVersionNumber(): CarModel = copy().apply {
    versionNumber = VersionNumber(versionNumber.value + 1)
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that make it possible to create a ```CarModel``` object  with any version number?  because i would like to avoid that.

Comment: Yes, it would. I've updated my answer with what could then work (a private Setter for your VersionNumber property)